# Add domain to relative urls

Tags: jquery, replace

How can I add http://facebook.com to relative URL's contained within `#facebook_urls`? Eg:

```
<a href="/test.html">
```

becomes

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/test.html">
```

`#facebook_urls` also contains absolute urls, so I want to make sure I don't touch those.

Comment: Are the urls segregated by any means? I mean, be either class or name or property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('#facebook_urls a').each(function() {
  if(!this.href.match('^http')) {
    this.href = "http://facebook.com/" + this.href
  }
})
```